# Colorbox not working in some pages (added by Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, colorbox

i've been working on a Google Chrome extension that add's a button on the webpage, and this button opens a colorbox with a page of the extension loaded.

I have this code:

```
jQuery('#Link').click(function() {
    alert("click");
    logClrBox = jQuery('#Link').colorbox({
        iframe:true,
        width:'800', 
        height:'560',

    });
});
```

My problem is, sometimes the alert is shown, but sometimes the alert is not shown and the link goes directly to the webpage on the "href" attribute.

To add the button, i use this on a content script:

```
$("form").append("a element")
```

with no onclick function,only the href.

My first idea is that some pages have jquery also loaded, and this may cause a conflict, but i can't see any error on the console. Maybe it is the problem? In any case, how can i solve it?

If is not a conflict, any idea why i can't get it working?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked the console for some error/warning reports about your plugin?

Comment: yes, and no errors on the console. This is why i get surprised and asked here ;P Some pages simply opens the link on the tab, without click event

Comment: Did you tried to sync the operations in `$(document).ready(function());`? It seems to me that you might execute something not fully-loaded yet, which cause such problem, commonly. I would suggest to name your ids with unique values, which will prevent some conflicts with other plugins or even loaded web pages, for example instead of "#Link", you could use "#cb_link".

Comment: Hi, finally solved it. I don't know what was the problem, but changing the position of the button on the html solved it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This is strange, could be caused by some sort of cached data, I suppose something like this, or not the plugin was not re-enabled with the new source.